# loop with set_fact in ansible 2.13.2

Tags: ansible

I have a task that I use already and works as expected in Ansible ver. 2.9.17. The same task however behaves differently in version 2.13.

I have the following list element that I loop:

```py
vlan_list: [
             "uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER2/ap-TST-CUSTOMER2/epg-VLAN20"
             "uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER1/ap-TST-CUSTOMER1/epg-VLAN10"
             "uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER3/ap-TST-CUSTOMER3/epg-VLAN30"
           ]
```

and the task itself is as follows:

```py
- name: gather only IDs
  set_fact:
    epg_list: "{{ epg_list }} + [ '{{ item.split('/')[-1] | regex_replace('epg-VLAN') }}' ]"
  loop: "{{ vlan_list | flatten(levels=1) }}"
  when: vlan_list|length > 0
```

the output of the above task in ansible v2.9 is:

```py
ok: [my_host.com] => (item=uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER2/ap-TST-CUSTOMER2/epg-VLAN20) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "epg_list": [
            "20"
        ]
    }, 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": "uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER2/ap-TST-CUSTOMER2/epg-VLAN20"
}
ok: [my_host.com] => (item=uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER1/ap-TST-CUSTOMER1/epg-VLAN10) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "epg_list": [
            "20", 
            "10"
        ]
    }, 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": "uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER1/ap-TST-CUSTOMER1/epg-VLAN10"
}
ok: [my_host.com] => (item=uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER3/ap-TST-CUSTOMER3/epg-VLAN30) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "epg_list": [
            "20", 
            "10", 
            "30"
        ]
    }, 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": "uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER3/ap-TST-CUSTOMER3/epg-VLAN30"
}
```

the same task gives the following in v2.13: (deducted)

```py
.
.
.
ok: [my_host.com] => (item=uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER3/ap-TST-CUSTOMER3/epg-VLAN30) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "epg_list": "[] + [ '20' ] + [ '10' ] + [ '30' ]"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER3/ap-TST-CUSTOMER3/epg-VLAN30"
.
.
.
```

In the second output, there is an empty list and every list is concanted with a `+`
So my question is, what I'm doing is the normal way, or is there a best practice way to loop over a list and extract some values from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact it was "working" in ansible 2.9 is pure coincidence. Your `set_fact` task has the wrong syntax which should be (adding a bit of security when the variable is not first defined):

```yaml
- name: gather only IDs
  set_fact:
    epg_list: "{{ epg_list | d([]) + [item.split('/')[-1] | regex_replace('epg-VLAN')] }}"
  loop: "{{ vlan_list | flatten(levels=1) }}"
  when: vlan_list | length > 0
```

*Note that the `flatten` filter is purely optionnal if your data always looks like the one you pasted in your question*

Moreover, using a `loop` (and most probably using `set_fact` too) is an over-kill in this situation as you can get your result with a single jinja2 expression as demonstrated in the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Pushing a static list for this example to work
    vlan_list:
      - uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER2/ap-TST-CUSTOMER2/epg-VLAN20
      - uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER1/ap-TST-CUSTOMER1/epg-VLAN10
      - uni/tn-TST-CUSTOMER3/ap-TST-CUSTOMER3/epg-VLAN30

    # This will return an empty list if the above var is undefined
    # This will return whatever list as long as `vlan_list`
    # is defined by the time you call the var in your playbook.
    # This will work with a registered var as well.
    epg_list: '{{ vlan_list | d([])
      | map("regex_replace", "^.*/epg-VLAN([0-9]+)$", "\g<1>")
      | map("int") | sort }}'

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: epg_list
```

which gives:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "epg_list": [
        10,
        20,
        30
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, it works. I didn't mention it in the question above but I have had an empty list variable defined in the vars section of the playbook so that loop works. Other than that I guess, I need to use ```set_fact``` because the list element ```vlan_list``` is provided by another task during the play am I guessing correctly?

Comment: No you don't need to use `set_fact`. You can keep a simple definition in vars. Refined the example to make this clear and added a default to empty list if `vlan_list` is undefined